# Autocomplete for Firebase on VScode

Tags: javascript, firebase, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

Installed VScode and package for javascript.
I'm writing code with firebase like below.
I was using Xcode and it autocomplete worked well but VScode doesn't.
How can I fix it?

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("test")...
```

**What I did** 
Installed Firebase Snippets but it was not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio IntelliCode extension.

Comment: I installed it. But it was not perfect.